# How to disable Word 2013 PDF edition?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ms-word

I'm currently working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to open a .docx file and convert to PDF. In order to do that, I'm doing this :

1. Opening the .docx file with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents.Open()`
2. Exporting this document as a PDF with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.ExportAsFixedFormat()`

I used this method ("Call the Protect method of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document that you want to protect") : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178793(v=vs.110).aspx

I have my PDF file, but I can open it in Microsoft Word and edit it... I don't want this PDF to be editable and I must use Word automation to make the PDF.

My question is in the title:

How to disable Word 2013 PDF edition?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. I'm sure the `Protect` method you posted can protect parts of the Word document itself, but not the PDF when it's exported. I can't see anything on the documentation for [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.exportasfixedformat.aspx) that indicates an overload for protection. Unfortunately I can't find 100% proof on this so just a comment for now.

Comment: Out of interest, why must you use Word automation over any other library?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Equalsk. I even tried to change the value of the properties `Final` and `ReadOnlyRecommanded` on the document but it didn't worked.
Also, I tried to open it with `ReadOnly` but after that I couldn't export it as a PDF.

Comment: @Equalsk I must use Word automation because the guys who made the application said that they don't want to use other libraries to do that. I'm new in this company and this is a little company (6 employes, including me) so I don't want to _fight_ with them for the moment ^^ 
The application was written by one guy and he don't want other people to modify all his code... Diplomacy is a hard thing.

Comment: I can see you're in a difficult position. Sounds like your colleague needs a kick. If I find something I'll let you know, but Word was not designed to convert PDFs for you and as such lacks the functionality (such as protect) that a dedicated library would have so I'm sticking by what I said. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Equalsk, I hope that they will accept to use a dedicated library to do that. I'm going to work on it. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the way Word converts to PDF. There are some options that can be set, using the method you use, but the basic code can't be changed. If you want special things it might be worthwhile to invest in Adobe Acrobat and/Or its API. Since PDF is Adobe's file format its product will have all the special things - it doesn't license some of these things to third parties (such as Microsoft).